# Python BeautifulSoup - Different results with find and findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some text embedded in HTML using BeautifulSoup, using the "text" attribute.
Playing around with "find" and "findAll", I notice something strange and cannot get my head around why it behaves in this way...

```
import re
import BeautifulSoup

doc = "<html><head><title>Page title</title><title>Author name</title></head>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

# find test
test1 = soup1.find('title',text=re.compile("Page")) 
print test1 # Returns "Page title"

# findAll test
test2 = soup1.findAll('title',text=re.compile("Page")) 
print test2 # Returns "[<title>Page title</title>, <title>Author name</title>]"
```

In the second test, shouldn't the parser return the same results as in the first example?
The second test should be returning all 'title' tags whose text contains "Page", and yet it returns the second title tag too.

Is this expected or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#arg-text) seems to suggest that the `text` and `name` arguments are mutually exclusive. But, it says, if `text` is specified, `name` is ignored, In your case it seems to do the opposite.

Comment: I did see this; I've never had a problem using find, but perhaps its a typo in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected on BeautifulSoup 3.2.0:

```
>>> soup.find('title',text=re.compile("Page")) 
u'Page title'
>>> soup.findAll('title',text=re.compile("Page")) 
[u'Page title']
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the results for BeautifulSoup version 4.7 in python3.7

```
>>> soup.find('title', text=re.compile('Page'))
    <title>Page title</title>
>>> soup.findAll('title', text=re.compile('Page'))
   [<title>Page title</title>]
```